# Mongodb aggregation to return data from multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a database with `comments` and `users`. I'm attempting to run an aggregation to get data returned in a certain format with populated nested documents (see below)

Some comments are `replies` to other comments, which is tracked by the `reply_to` property in the comment model. There can be many replies for the same comment.

What I'm attempting to do is return comment documents in an array, with all of the replies in a `replies` property in each comment, along with some user data (display_name).

Here is sample data:

comments

```json
    {
        "_id": "63acacb169f733cf45f22e51",
        "user": "63acacb169f733cf45f22e4f",
        "body": "I love this recipe!",
        "rating": 5,
        "article_id": "Y4Iu0hIAACsAohcA",
        "status": "Approved",
        "createdAt": "2022-12-28T20:53:05.761Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-12-28T20:55:05.837Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "63acb0df4f4adc6e16001fe7",
        "user": "636261acb4ce6745b38d8785",
        "reply_to": "63acac8569f733cf45f22e49",
        "article_id": "Y4Iu0hIAACsAohcA",
        "status": "Trashed",
        "createdAt": "2022-12-28T21:10:55.698Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-12-28T21:13:27.544Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "63acb16d4f4adc6e16001fef",
        "user": "636261acb4ce6745b38d8785",
        "body": "I Love it too!",
        "reply_to": "63acac8569f733cf45f22e49",
        "article_id": "Y4Iu0hIAACsAohcA",
        "status": "Approved",
        "createdAt": "2022-12-28T21:13:17.665Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-12-28T21:13:29.199Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

users

```json
 {
        "_id": "63ac944ac2faa2dd59f6a492",
        "display_name": "Jane Doe",
        "email": "dfasfasdf@example.com",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "63acacb169f733cf45f22e4f",
        "display_name": "Juice Guy",
        "email": "juiceguy@example.com",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Here's an example of how I want the data returned when I query for comments by `article_id`, so I can display all comments and replies on the page for the user.

```json
  {
    "_id": "63acacb169f733cf45f22e51",
    "user": {
      "display_name": "John Doe",
    },
    "body": "I love this recipe!",
    "rating": 5,
    "createdAt": "2022-12-28T20:53:05.761Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-12-28T20:55:05.837Z",
    "replies": [
      {
        "body": "I love this too!",
        "user": { 
            "display_name": "Juice Guy" 
        },
        "createdAt": "2022-12-28T20:53:05.761Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-12-28T20:55:05.837Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've been playing with `$group` and `$lookup` but with the nested documents I can't get all the data I want in one aggregation. Can someone help?

Comment: I think $graphLookup might be helpful here

Comment: This seems to be a bit of an anti-pattern for MongoDB. More ideally `replies` would be stored in an array *inside* whatever `comment` document they are replying to (i.e. an array of embedded `comment` documents). Is there a reason this data wouldn't ever live together? This has a number of advantages for making querying easier, etc.

Comment: @JustinJenkins that depends on the goal of the app.  Storing the replies in an array in the original post requires updating that original post every time there is a reply, and handling the race conditions when multiple replies arrive simultaneously, while this schema permits each reply to be a completely atomic insert.

Comment: @Joe I would agree this depends on the "goal" of the app, but for different reasons. Like is this one level of comments + replies or a massive levels comments on comments on comments? Clearly the less bounded the more problematic it could be. If it were bounded this shouldn't be an issue, and it makes querying *way* easier. I would say the race condition doesn't seem to be a particular issue here? Doing a simple append to the array should be sufficient. That said, every write in MongoDB is already a atomic operation on the document level, including modifying even multiple embedded documents.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I was just pointing out that we don't have enough information about the structure and goals of this application to make that choice in an informed manner.

Answer (score 0):

To get these in a single document, you would need to:

- $match for documents that do not have a `reply_to` field (top-level comments)
- $lookup from comments, matching local `_id` with foreign `reply_to`
- $unwind the replies
- $lookup from users matching local `user` with remote `_id`
- $lookup from users matching local `replies.user` with remote `_id`
- $project to select/remove fields as desred
- $group by `_id`, retaining all of the top level fields, and $push the replies back into an array
- $replaceRoot/$project to finalize the shape of the returned document